# How to find the sum of an entered list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am still very new to python and working on a school assignment. The program should be a loop that allows the user to enter a series of number that will keep going as long as the number entered is 0 or greater. Once a negative number is entered the program should create a sum of all numbers entered. Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
#This program calculates the sum of multiple numbers

#Initialize accumulator
total = 0

#Calculate the sum of numbers
while keep_going >= 0:
    keep_going = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    total += keep_going
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Calculate the sum of numbers
saved_numbers = [] # A list of numbers to fill up. 
while True: # A way to write 'keep doing this until I stop ('break' in this case...)'
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if number < 0: # If the number is negative
        break # Exits the current while loop for us. 
    else: # Otherwise, save the number.
        saved_numbers.append(number) 

sum = sum(saved_numbers) # Getting the sum of the numbers the user entered!
print(sum)
```

Comment: This answer was nicer without the comments, IMO.

Comment: thanks for feedback... added them after considering OP was new and needed some detail

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think ordinary text is better for most of this kind of explanation. Just my personal opinion that it's best to model good coding practice in answers, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackOverflow Christian, and welcome into the great world of programming =)

Few remarks about your code:

- `keep_going = >-0` makes no sense. `>` is a comparison operator, you have to use it to compare two expressions, e.g. `var1 > var2`, and it will return a boolean.
- `while keep_going == 0:` is a nice start, but won't do what you want. The loop has to keep going if the entered number is greater or equal to zero, not only if `keep_going` is equal to zero. Change `==` by `>=`.
- `int(input('Enter a number: '))` is the way to go, but why did you use it twice ? On a side note, you're only storing the input number in a variable on the second times.
- Finally, you'll need to actually use `total` in your loop to store the user input.

Good luck !

PS: While stackoverflow is really nice to quickly get a solution, I really advice you to actually understand why your code is wrong, and why the provided solution works. It will greatly help you becoming a good programmer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler. You do not need the `keep_going` variable. Just use the `total` variable and add to the variable if the number entered is 0 or greater than 0. Exit the while loop if number is less than 0 :

```
#Initialize accumulator
total = 0

#Calculate the sum of numbers
while(True):
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if num < 0:
        break
    else:
        total = total + num

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep  track of entered numbers and calculate sum later using python `in-built` `sum` function.

```
keep_going = int(input('Enter a number: '))
entered_nums = []
while keep_going >= 0:
    entered_nums.append(keep_going)
    keep_going = int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Entered numbers : ', entered_nums)
print('Entered numbers sum : ', sum(entered_nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

That can also be done with `recursion` instead of a `while`. i.e.:

```
def count_total(total=0):
    keep_going = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if keep_going >= 0:
        total += keep_going
        count_total(total)
    else:
        print('Total : %d' % total)


count_total()
```

Comment: While I truly love recursion, introducing it to a new programmer is borderline evil... here is your +1 :'D

Comment: Would a programmer, any programmer, ever actually do this? No.

Comment: @NiziL  at least it's borderline :'D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
def func():
    i = 0
    while i >= 0:
        i = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        yield (i >= 0) * i

print(sum(func()))
```

Keep in mind that in Python `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`.